# Problem with create temporary table mysql in java program

Tags: java, mysql

I'm new on java programming.

I've a problem with creation a temporary table in Java..

```
Database db = new Database();

String query="create temporary table sconti (codcon int(11) not null, " + 
            " sigcos char(4) not null, codgru char(4) not null, codsgr char(4) not null, " + 
            " desgru char(100) not null, dessgr char(100) not null, sconto1 double(16,4) not null, " + 
            " sconto2 double(16,4) not null,sconto3 double(16,4) not null,primary key(codcon,sigcos,codgru,codsgr));";

db.executequery(query);
```

With first instruction I connect to the database then do  the query with executequery

the debug error is:

```
Field 'codgru' doesn't have a default value
```

Comment: Your create table statements [seems to be working](https://rextester.com/GPQXG90400) directly on MySQL.  Maybe the API you are using is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a column as `not null`, you have to set a Default value. This is missing for some columns in  query.
So remove `not null` or add a default value.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html